# background image disappear because of left-panel

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I've a jQuery mobile app with a left panel menü. If I click on the panel, my background disappears.

I'm not sure, with code I should post to you. Thats the CSS code for my background:

```
[data-role=page] {
    background-image: url(../images/pattern.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: You can add bg img to specific pages programmatically. Create a class, add/remove it on pagebeforeshow/pagebeforehide. But you still need to keep an eye on panel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile 1.4, when a *panel* is opened for the first time, it wraps *content* div in a `.ui-panel-wrapper` div. This div overrides *page*'s div background.

This behavior occurs when *panel*'s `data-display` is set to either `push` or `reveal`, but not `overlay`.

To solve this problem, add `background-image` to both `[data-role=page]` and `.ui-panel-wrapper` followed by `!important` to force override.

```css
[data-role=page], .ui-panel-wrapper {
  background-image: url(../bg.png) !important;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/rbDJ2/)**

Comment: Thank's Omar for your solution. Meanwhile, I've a similar problem. Maybe you've a solution again :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941065/different-background-images-and-left-panel-bug

Comment: Thanks so much for the easy solution!! Saved me loads of time