# different background images and left-panel bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile 1.4 and if I click on the left panel, my background disappears. I solved this bug with help of Omar (thanks a lot).

**Aim:**

- homePage should has a dark background
- all other pages should have a light background

**Problem 1:**

- If I click on panel on homePage, it works.
- If I go to contactPage and click on panel, the background changes

**Problem 2:**

- If I go to contactPage, open panel, close panel and go back to homePage - I can not open the panel

---

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ULuvu/1/

**Code:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="homePage" class="bg-dark">
    <div id="nav-panel" data-role="panel">
        <a href="#my-header" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn">Close panel</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h3>homePage - DARK BACKGROUND</h3>
        <a href= "#nav-panel" data-role="button">Open Panel</a>
        <a href= "#contactPage" data-role="button">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="contactPage">
    <div id="nav-panel" data-role="panel">
        <a href="#my-header" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn">Close panel</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h3>CONTACT - LIGHT BACKGROUND</h3>
        <a href= "#nav-panel" data-role="button">Open Panel</a>
        <a href= "#homePage" data-role="button">back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
/* LIGHT BACKGROUND */
[data-role=page], .ui-panel-wrapper {
    background-image: url(http://bglabs.evade.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/stylish-floral-pattern.png) !important;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

/* DARK BACKGROUND only homePage */
.bg-dark, .ui-panel-wrapper {
    background-image: url(http://bglabs.evade.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/black-mosaic-tiles.png) !important;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the same *panel* for all pages, I do recommend using *external panel* instead of adding the same markup to each and every page.

*External panel* is placed outside *page* div and can be called on every page. You only need to initialize it one time and enhance contents inside it.

```
<!-- external panel -->
<div data-role="panel">
  <!-- contents -->
</div>

<!-- pages -->
<div data-role="page">
  <!-- contents -->
</div>

<div data-role="page">
  <!-- contents -->
</div>
```

Initialize *external panel*:

```
$(function () {
  $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();
});
```

Add class `.bg-dark` to *homepage*, and `.bg-light` to other pages and use CSS below.

```
/* LIGHT BACKGROUND */
.bg-light, .bg-light .ui-panel-wrapper {
  background-image: url(light.png) !important;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
/* DARK BACKGROUND only homePage */
.bg-dark, .bg-dark .ui-panel-wrapper {
 background-image: url(dark.png) !important;
 background-repeat: repeat;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6BrSC/)**

Comment: Hi Omar, a external panel it's a good idea. There is one little problem. I've updated your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6BrSC/3/ . If you open the panel, click on contact and click on contact again, the panel should close, but it remains open. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @struct you're calling the same page, so it remains open. If you wasn't to close it, check href of clicked anchor, if it equals active page, close it. `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");`. And `$("#panel").panel("close");`.

Comment: Is it possible that you update your JSFiddle with this case? :) Otherwise thanks for help.

Comment: @Struct you're welcome. I'll let you know once I update the demo :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this fiddle where both your problems should be fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/ULuvu/2/

**Problem 1:**
I fixed this issue with adding `#contactPage .ui-panel-wrapper` and `#homePage .ui-panel-wrapper` to the CSS.

**Problem 2:**
It seemed the problem was caused by the duplicate ID `id="nav-panel"`. I renamed the one on the homepage to "nav-panel-homepage". Now it works fine.